# The name 'CertificateAuthenticationDefaults' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net, mtls

I'm trying to configure mTLS authentication with ASP.NET core 3.1 by using the example from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth#aspnet-5-aspnet-core-31-sample) but getting the error below

*Error  CS0103  The name 'CertificateAuthenticationDefaults' does not exist in the current context*

The code I'm using for Startup.cs is below:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication1.Data;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            // Configure the application to use the protocol and client ip address forwared by the frontend load balancer
            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardedHeaders =
                    ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
            });

            // Configure the application to client certificate forwarded the frontend load balancer
            services.AddCertificateForwarding(options => { options.CertificateHeader = "X-ARR-ClientCert"; });

            // Add certificate authentication so when authorization is performed the user will be created from the certificate
            services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCertificate();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseForwardedHeaders();
            app.UseCertificateForwarding();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }


}
```

Any suggestinos on fix will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to overcome the error I have to add the following statement in the code :

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate;

and install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate 3.1.20 package.